# How to send images using sms without using internet

Tags: android-camera2, android-camerax, android-sms

I want implement an android application in kotlin where i can send capured photo or images via sms .I would like someone to explain me the process , how it works and how could i figure this out ?

Comment: Will the receiver also have you app installed? Because then you could possibly encode image data to base64 and then decode on the receiver side back to image.

Comment: @Orcun but is there a possibility to do it without installing the app on the receiver side ?

Comment: Not sure tbh. If the receiver does not have the app installed, a more creative approach is required. Maybe sending it in a format a browser can open when pasted without using internet? Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75590871/2895045
Idea is converting a tiny image to base64 string and make a browser open it without internet. 
Try to paste the data into browser address field and you will see the image directly.